# Spring MVC - How to write Single config or a user defined config file to map multiple controller except RequestMapping mechanism

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to develop one spring mvc application. I don't want to write @RequestMapping("/controllerfunction").. with in the controller. I want to write all request in one xml or any file to map corresponding controller and its function. Is there any way to develop this kind of logic? Please share.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a [`HandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html), but using `@RequestMapping` is best-practice; why do you want to avoid using these?

Comment: Thanks beerbajay, I want to write more controller and function then I don't want to allow direct url accessing thats why.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't quite make sense. Your XML will have to map from `/some/path` to `someFunction(...)` anyway; doing `@RequestMapping public void someFunction(...)` doesn't change how a user can access that url. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Nothing beerbajay. @RequestMapping() is best way right?